# Executar mensagem de produto não encontrado

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, css

```js
 <?
 public function busca()
    {
        $busca             = '%' . sanitize_text_field($_POST['busca']) . '%';
        $nome_categoria    = '';
        $produto_categoria = array();
        $link_categoria    = '';
        $categorias        = SF()->query->run('SELECT ge.id_grupo, ge.nome, ge.URL_IMAGEM
                                                 FROM #BANCO#.grupos_ecommerce ge 
                                                WHERE ge.NOME LIKE %s 
                                                LIMIT 1', array(
                                                          $busca
                                              ));

        
        if (isset($categorias[0])) {
            $produtos_categoria = SF()->query->run('SELECT p.ID_PRODUTO, p.NOME  
                                                      FROM #BANCO#.produtos p
                                                     WHERE p.id_grupo_ecommerce = %d
                                                       and p.id_conta = #ID_CONTA#
                                                     LIMIT 10', array(
                                                                $categorias[0]['id_grupo']
                                                    ));                                       
            $nome_categoria  = $categorias[0]['nome'];
            $link_categoria = $nome_categoria . '-' . $categorias[0]['id_grupo'];
        }
        
            $produtos_busca = SF()->query->run('SELECT p.ID_PRODUTO, p.NOME  
                                                  FROM #BANCO#.produtos p
                                                 WHERE p.NOME LIKE %s
                                                   and p.id_conta = #ID_CONTA#
                                                 LIMIT 6', array(
                                                            $busca
                                                ));
                                                
        
        $quantidade_produtos = SF()->query->run('SELECT count(1) as quantidade
                                                   FROM #BANCO#.produtos p
                                                  WHERE p.NOME LIKE %s', array(
                                                                         $busca
                                                ));
        
        $quantidade_produtos = isset($quantidade_produtos[0]) ? $quantidade_produtos[0]['quantidade'] : 0;
        
        $link_final     = add_query_arg('busca', $_POST['busca'], snap_get_pagina_url('loja'));
        $link_categoria = add_query_arg('categoria', $link_categoria, snap_get_pagina_url('loja'));
        
        foreach ($produtos_busca as $key => $produto) {
            $produtos_busca[$key]['link_produto'] = snap_get_produto_url($produto['NOME'], $produto['ID_PRODUTO']);
            $produto = new SNAP_Produto($produto['ID_PRODUTO']);
            $produtos_busca[$key]['preco'] = $produto->preco;
            $produtos_busca[$key]['LINK'] = $produto->imagens[0];
            $produtos_busca[$key]['REFERENCIA'] = $produto->referencia;
            $produtos_busca[$key]['DETALHES'] = $produto->detalhes;
            error_log( $produto->referencia);
        }
        
        foreach ($produtos_categoria as $key => $produto) {
            $produtos_categoria[$key]['link_produto'] = snap_get_produto_url($produto['NOME'], $produto['ID_PRODUTO']);
            $produto = new SNAP_Produto($produto['ID_PRODUTO']);
            $produtos_categoria[$key]['preco'] = $produto->preco;
            $produtos_categoria[$key]['LINK'] = $produto->imagens[0];
            $produtos_categoria[$key]['REFERENCIA'] = $produto->referencia;
            $produtos_categoria[$key]['DETALHES'] = $produto->detalhes;
        }
        
        
        wp_send_json(array(
            'codigo' => 0,
            'mensagem' => 'RESULTADO',
            'produtos' => $produtos_busca,
            'link' => $link_final,
            'link_categoria' => $link_categoria,
            'produtos_categoria' => $produtos_categoria,
            'nome_categoria' => $nome_categoria,
            'quantidade' => $quantidade_produtos
        ));
    }
}
?>
```

toda vez que um produto não for encontrado eu preciso ue apareça uma mensagem de produto nao encontrado, preciso fazer isso em Jquery

Comment: Dá uma olhadela em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. De qualquer maneira o melhor será usar um ``plugin`` de js para a notificação. Tem o ``toastr`` é muito bom

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

Eu sou iniciante então, se não funcionar não fique bravo :3

Então amigo, você quer retornar uma msg que não foi encotrado?
Você pode fazer uma sql com "SELECT NOME_DA_COLUNA FROM NOME_DA_TABELA WHERE _NOME_DA_COLUNA Like '**Busca_do_usuario**'";

Exemplo:
SELECT nome FROM produtos WHERE nome Like 'Televisão';

Caso houver algum nome *Televisão* na minha coluna "nome" da tabela produtos irá retornar um valor maior que 1 sendo assim

if($resultado_da_sql == 0){
echo "Produto pesquisado não encontrado";
}